# The error facing Maybe it is because dialogflow version is changed. The error from firebase is mentioned below it is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    console.log("request.body.queryResult.parameters:", request.body.queryResult.parameters);

    const parameters = request.body.queryResult.parameters;

    response.send({
        fulfillmentText:
            `${parameters.given-name} your hotel booking request for ${parameters.RoomType} room is forwarded for
             ${parameters.person} persons, we will contact you on ${parameters.email} soon`
    });
});
```

The error I am getting in Firebase is:

```
ReferenceError: name is not defined
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:17:33)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:49:16)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do something that JavaScript doesn't allow.  Look at the beginning of this string:

```
`${parameters.given-name} your hotel booking request for ${parameters.RoomType} room is forwarded for
```

You're trying to interpolate the value of the expression `parameters.given-name` as a value here.  However, that doesn't evaluate the way you expect.  That expression is telling JavaScript to subtract the value of `name` from `parameters.given`.  Since you don't have a variable called `name`, the code crashes with "name is not defined".

If you're trying to access a property called called "given-name" from parameters, you should do it like this instead:

```
`${parameters['given-name']} ... `
```